# Pivot Table from Query involving Months in TeraData

Tags: sql, count, pivot, teradata, aggregate-functions

I have a table generated from a query in TeraData that looks like this:

```
User_ID     Transaction_Month      Number_of_Visits
 123              1                       1
 123              2                       2
 221              4                       1
 123              5                       2
 221              3                       5
```

I am trying to create a Pivot table of sorts that will look like:

```
User_ID     Month_1    Month_2    Month_3  Month_4 ..... Month_12
 123
```

That will store the number of visits in each month column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
    sum(case when transaction_month =  1 then number_of_visits else 0 end) month_1,
    sum(case when transaction_month =  2 then number_of_visits else 0 end) month_2,
    ...
    sum(case when transaction_month = 12 then number_of_visits else 0 end) month_12
from mytable
group by user_id
```